# Can someone tell me what’s wrong with this code?

Tags: jsp, servlets

This doesn’t create any errors but my data is not sent to the database. Both JSP and servlet pages are working properly but I cannot find the problem with the connection. I have created previous projects using the same method and they worked perfectly.

catering.jsp

```
<div class="cat_book_wrapper" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-offset-0 padding-right padding-left">
                <div class="cat_book_form wow zoom">    
                    <form method="POST" action="Catering">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Date</td>
                                <td><input type="date" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" id="cus_date" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>No.Of People</td>
                                <td>
                                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="cus_ppl">
                                        <option value="1">Select from list</option>
                                        <option value="2">30</option>
                                        <option value="3">40</option>
                                        <option value="4">50</option>
                                        <option value="5">100</option>
                                        <option value="6">150</option>
                                        <option value="7">200</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Venue</td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="No.45, Kadawatha, Wattala" id="venue" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Contact Person</td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="A.M De Alwis" id="cus_name" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Phone Number</td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0777456345" id="cus_num" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email Id</td>
                                <td><input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Info@yourdomain.com" id="cus_email" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="submit" value="book now" class="btn search_toggle" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Catering.java (Servlet)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Catering
 */
@WebServlet("/Catering")
public class Catering extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Catering() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String cus_date = request.getParameter("cus_date");
            String cus_ppl = request.getParameter("cus_ppl");
            String venue = request.getParameter("venue");
            String cus_name = request.getParameter("cus_name");
            String cus_num = request.getParameter("cus_num");
            String cus_email = request.getParameter("cus_email");

            String sql = "insert into cater(cus_date,cus_ppl,venue,cus_name,cus_num,cus_email) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sujanee", "root", "");
            java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, cus_date);
            ps.setString(2, cus_ppl);
            ps.setString(3, venue);
            ps.setString(4, cus_name);
            ps.setString(5, cus_num);
            ps.setString(6, cus_email);

            ps.executeUpdate();
            response.sendRedirect("cateringDisplay.jsp");
            return;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put a breakpoint on `doPost` method and check if you can get the request parameters.

It seems that you are missing the attribute `name` in the form. This represents the HTTP request parameter name.

Try this:

```
 <div class="cat_book_wrapper" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div
                    class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-offset-0 padding-right padding-left">
                    <div class="cat_book_form wow zoom">

                        <form method="POST" action="Catering">
                            <table>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Date</td>
                                    <td><input type="date" class="form-control datepicker"
                                        placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" id="cus_date" name="cus_date" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>No.Of People</td>
                                    <td><select class="form-control selectpicker" id="cus_ppl" name="cus_ppl">
                                            <option value="1">Select from list</option>
                                            <option value="2">30</option>
                                            <option value="3">40</option>
                                            <option value="4">50</option>
                                            <option value="5">100</option>
                                            <option value="6">150</option>
                                            <option value="7">200</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Venue</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="No.45, Kadawatha, Wattala" id="venue"  name="venue" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Contact Person</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="A.M De Alwis" id="cus_name"  name="cus_name" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Phone Number</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="0777456345" id="cus_num" name="cus_num" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Email Id</td>
                                    <td><input type="email" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Info@yourdomain.com" id="cus_email" name="cus_email" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="submit" value="book now"
                                        class="btn search_toggle" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes. that was the exact problem with my coding. Thank you so much for correcting it and letting me know the issue.